# Laravel - How to get checkboxes value with the same name properly?

Tags: laravel

My model (table with 2 primary keys and are foreign key on the same time) :

```
class FormationPersonnel extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = ['cin', 'id_form'];
  public $incrementing = false;
}
```

I create checkboxes with JQuery, Ajax like so :

```
var grabData = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      grabData +=
      `<div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cin[]" id="`+data[i]["cin"]+`" class="custom-control-input" value="`+data[i]["cin"]+`">
        <label for="`+data[i]["cin"]+`" class="custom-control-label">`+data[i]["cin"]+' '+data[i]["nom"]+' '+data[i]["prenom"]+`</label>
      </div>
      </div>`;
    }
    personnelsInput.html("");
    personnelsInput.append(grabData);
```

which I give the checkboxes the same name as :

```
 name="cin[]"
```

In My controller I use this code, but is not storing any data from checkboxes :

```
$cins = $request->cin; //I get inputs like this
foreach ($cins as $cin) {
$form_pers = new FormationPersonnel; //create new record
if ($request->has($cin)) { 
  $form_pers->id_form = $request->input('id_form');
  $form_pers->cin = $request->input($cin);
  $form_pers->save(); //save data
  }
}
```

What is the correct way ?

Comment: first make sure `cin[]` is coming to controller or not! then the problem is in your `if statement`, you check if the `$form_pers->$cin != null` but the `$form_pers` is null because `$form_pers = new FormationPersonnel`, try `dd($form_pers)`

Comment: what I mean null is, your `$form_pers` doesn't have a value `$cin`, in your `if statement` put `else` function and see what u got there

Comment: so you edit the question but why if condition to check if checkbox is checked or not? The $cin only contain the checkbox value `checked`, then compare it's value (what value to compare, $cin and what)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to check whether the `Model` has cin or not is

**Edited**

based on the comment we put, I think I know what you're trying to do, so do it like below code to get what you need.

- *note*

you don't know what `$cins` values so that's why you use `if()`. No need to check whether the user check (checkbox) or not. because the checked value only send by form. please try to know what data you have in your variable before coding.

I recommended you to use dd() or print_r() or others https://laraveldaily.com/echoing-dd-vs-var_dump-vs-print_r/ to check the data you got in your variable.

```
$cins = $request->cin; //getting all checked (from checkbox) data

foreach ($cins as $cin) {
 $form_pers = new FormationPersonnel; //new model
 $form_pers->id_form = $request->id_form; //get name="id_form" from form
 $form_pers->cin = $cin; //put cin value (loop)
 $form_pers->save(); //save
}
```

Comment: No, `$form_pers->$cin` is not from the model, it's from the checkbox input

Comment: and I use `$form_pers = new FormationPersonnel;` to create new record, the condition mean if the checkbox is checked or not, then it will create a new record

Comment: can you share (or edit question) your whole controller

Comment: or change `variable` to `$others` to check differently otherwise your method never works

Comment: `$cins = $request->cin;` is correct to get inputs ?

Comment: I edit the answer, please check.. and if it is correct then marked as accepted answer to help others

Comment: Thank you brother for your effort to give me the correct answer !